# Losing focus from text input area in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, xamarin.ios

I have a text box in a view, when I focus it the keyboard pops up, I can type some stuff in, but when I'm done with it I can't lose focus to it. Like if I click outside the text box the keyboard remains.

How can I get rid of the keyboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs:

> It is your application’s responsibility to dismiss the keyboard at the
>   time of your choosing. You might dismiss the keyboard in response to a
>   specific user action, such as the user tapping a particular button in
>   your user interface. You might also configure your text field delegate
>   to dismiss the keyboard when the user presses the “return” key on the
>   keyboard itself. To dismiss the keyboard, send the
>   resignFirstResponder message to the text field that is currently the
>   first responder. Doing so causes the text field object to end the
>   current editing session (with the delegate object’s consent) and hide
>   the keyboard.

Here is one way to do it using a UITextFieldDelegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Make sure you hook up the delegate to the textField.

Comment: You can also add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the containing view (or any other view) and call `[textField resignFirstResponder]` when this recognizer fires (be cautious with blocking other interaction with this though).